# import not working in typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, angular

Hi i'm using jetBrain WebStorm
and trying to use typescript in order to learn angular2

for some reason typescript compiler gives an error when I am trying to import angular2.

```
import {Component , View} from 'angular2';
```

throws

> Error:(1, 32) TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> Error:(1, 1) TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

I used npm in order to install angular2-dependencies.

is there anything I need to do in order to use it ?
I read that I need to configure typescript to --moduleResolution node
Can anyone have solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: Download Webstorm 11EAP, configure a tscong.json file and instruct webstorm to use the built 1.6.2 controller and your tsconfig file. This will save you from a lot of pain

Comment: I think instead import {Component , View} from 'angular2'; you should use import {Component , View} from 'angular2/angular2';